# HTML5 Canvas not drawing lines past 2040 in either direction

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Edit: Ran the code on a more powerful computer and the grid rendered correctly. Possible hardware limitation? Computer where the problem occurred was a Samsung series 3 Chromebook. I'm thinking it has to do with trying to draw too many lines at the same time. Will test later.

I'm trying to draw a grid onto a canvas using the lineTo() method. The lines draw properly in the beginning, but any line that is drawn completely past 2048 pixels either down or to the right doesn't show up. Line going from inside this point to past it still show up on the other side, just lines that only are only drawn past the point don't show up.

Here's my JavaScript:

```
function drawGrid() {
        //data.tiles is the map stored as an array of arrays
        //tilesize = 60

        var bw = data.tiles[0].length * tilesize;
        var bh = data.tiles.length * tilesize;

        ctx.beginPath();

        for (i = bw; i >= 0; i -= tilesize) {
            ctx.moveTo(i, 0);
            ctx.lineTo(i, bh);
        }
        for (i = bh; i >= 0; i -= tilesize) {
            ctx.moveTo(0, i);
            ctx.lineTo(bw,i);
        }

        ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
        ctx.stroke();
    }
```

I've checked the data.tiles variable, and it's reading the right number. Really have no idea what I messed up here.

Comment: Are you sure this doesn't have to do with the way you are displaying the canvas?

Comment: Yeah, I can see images rendered past that point, just not lines.

Comment: I have a feeling the exact limit is probably 2048 (2^11), not 2040.

Comment: Can you adda jsfiddle?

Answer (score 3):

HTML Canvas has a maximum render area depending on your browser & hardware.

once you exceed these limits well your done pretty much.

try pre-rendering or use multiple canvas' positioned with CSS.

Comment: Is it possible that drawImage() could have a farther range? Because there are images rendering past the 2048 mark, just not any lines that only exist past that range.

Comment: yeah images on a canvas are just like images anywhere else the have a referenced file that gets pulled. where as your lines get drawn by the engine at that point in time so it requires much more processing power and will have more stringent confides within your canvas.

Comment: this will probs be better at explaining how tight html5 canvas can be than me http://blog.toggl.com/2013/05/6-performance-tips-for-html-canvas-and-createjs/

Answer (score 1):

If you can see images drawn beyond 2048 then there's no reason a lineTo wouldn't be drawn also.

In the code you calculate `bw` and `bh` in different ways. You might check if this is a problem. If not, we'll need to see more code.

```
// bw uses data.tiles[0]

var bw = data.tiles[0].length * tilesize;

// bh uses data.tiles with no subscript

var bh = data.tiles.length * tilesize;
```